# Saxonica EE : compilation of xslt and transformation can we overwrite or ignore select value of

Tags: xslt, saxon

we are using saxonica EE license , i want to know if we can ignore or overwrite (ignore is preferred) select value of (which calls some other apps logic, which we want to ignore), example code as below

```
<xsl:value-of select="cpi:setHeader($exchange, 'content-type', 'application/xml')"/>
```

here want to ignore this select, it doesnt have any significance in the over logic of transformation.  is it possible to ignore a select in saxonica ?

Comment: There is `use-when`.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#conditional-inclusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write

```
<xsl:value-of 
   use-when="function-available('cpi:setHeader', 2)"
   select="cpi:setHeader($exchange, 'content-type', 'application/xml')"/>
```